# Delete Quote Items of Active Quotes with multiple items older than 5 minutes by Cron in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to truncate not delete the active quotes which have muliple quote items and older than 5 minutes. First I fetch the quote Collection like this:

```
$quoteCollection = $this->_quoteCollection->create()
                         ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
                         ->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('gt' => 1))
                         ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', array('lt' => $quoteTruncateTime));
```

But then how do I remove all the quote items of all active quote with a single loop? If I found each items of active quotes then multiple loops are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Here I did for customer logs to truncate the records.

- first Get the collection in a variable
- then write the query with the condition to get the records
- then put that collection in loop
- then call the delete function
  here is a small snippet

  ```
            $customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection();
            $customer_log_data = $customerCollection->getSelect()
                ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                ->columns(['e.entity_id', 'e.updated_at'])
                ->joinLeft(['cum_log' => 'customer_log'], 'e.entity_id = cum_log.customer_id', ['cum_log.last_login_at', 'cum_log.last_logout_at'])
                ->joinLeft(['profile' => 'profile'], 'e.entity_id = profile.magento_customer_id', ['profile.magento_customer_id'])
                ->joinLeft(['sales' => 'sales_order'], 'e.entity_id = sales.customer_id', ['order_id' => 'sales.entity_id'])
                ->where('profile.magento_customer_id is null  and sales.customer_id is null and (cum_log.last_login_at <= "' . $yearDays . '"|| cum_log.last_login_at is null and e.updated_at <= "' . $days . '"|| e.updated_at is null)')->group('e.entity_id')
                ->limit($recordValue);

            foreach ($customerCollection as $customerEntries)
            {
                $customerEntries->delete();
            }
  ```